# Consecutively restarting two Kafka Brokers., if the second node fails to start, the client continuously connecting to the second node

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

- Kafka Version： 2.8.1
- Kafka Cluster： 192.168.1.2:9092(1001), 192.168.1.3:9092(1002)
- Kafka Topic Config： 2 partition, 2 replicas
- Kafka Client Config：  bootstrap.servers: 192.168.1.2:9092,192.168.1.3:9092
- Operation: stop 1001 then start 1001，  stop 1002 and do not start

  - when 1001 stop， Kafka Client is normal
  - when 1001 start and 1002 stop， Kafka Client is keep connecting to 1002

```
[2023-05-16 23:27:02,450] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-123-1, groupId=123] Connection to node 1002 (192.168.1.3:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-05-16 23:27:03,004] DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-123-1, groupId=123] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-05-16 23:27:03,054] DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-123-1, groupId=123] Give up sending metadata request since no node is available (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-05-16 23:27:03,557] DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-123-1, groupId=123] Initialize connection to node 192.168.1.3:9092 (id: 1002 rack: null) for sending metadata request (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-05-16 23:27:03,557] DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-123-1, groupId=123] Initiating connection to node 192.168.1.3:9092 (id: 1002 rack: null) using address /192.168.1.3 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-05-16 23:27:03,559] DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-123-1, groupId=123] Set SASL client state to SEND_APIVERSIONS_REQUEST (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator)
[2023-05-16 23:27:03,559] DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-123-1, groupId=123] Creating SaslClient: client=null;service=kafka;serviceHostname=192.168.1.3;mechs=[PLAIN] (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthentica
[2023-05-16 23:27:03,560] DEBUG [Consumer clientId=consumer-123-1, groupId=123] Connection with 192.168.1.3 disconnected (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

I have made a preliminary diagnosis of the issue：

1. Kafka Clients use bootstrap server: 1001, 1002， this is only for init connection
2. When 1001 stop, Kafka Clients refresh metadata and remove 1001 from available node list，client only knows 1002
3. When 1001 start, Kafka Clients is not refreshing metadata, client still only know 1002
4. When 1002 stop， Kafka Clients Only have 1002 metadata，will still connect 1002.

In my opinion, when Kafka clients cannot find any available nodes to connect to, they should try to connect to the nodes listed in the bootstrap configuration instead of continuously connecting to node 1002.

Is this because of my incorrect usage, or is it an area for optimization where I should raise an issue to the community?

Comment: 1) Check description of property `metadata.max.age.ms` 2) If the leader partition was elected as 1002, there is no longer any reason to connect to 1001

Comment: Thank you for the reply 。
I tried to change metadata.max.age.ms to 1000ms, and it can avoid this problem to some extent, but I’m worried that if all the clients configure it this way, it will put some pressure on Kafka Broker.
I think Kafka Client should automatically try to reconnect using bootstrap.servers, because there is still one Broker alive, and the client should work normally.

Comment: It will automatically use others, but only on an interval defined by that property, or on disconnection. Or, as mentioned, if there's no data to use on another broker, there's no reason to connect with it, only the cluster controller and leader partitions need to be connected to

Comment: I have submitted an issuse to the community, you can keep an eye on the response
: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-15032

Comment: How did you verify 1001 became the leader broker, or controller again? Also, what happens when you use newest Kafka 3.x release?